# .htaccess remove subdirectories from URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL:

"http://www.example.com/pages/about.html"

I've been able to get rid of the file extensions and add a "/" at the end to create:

"http://www.example.com/pages/about/"

using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Next, I need to remove the pages subdirectory folder from the URL so that I get:

"http://www.example.com/about/"

Comment: Not possible.. You can get /services/service1/ and /about/ , but not /service1/ and /about/. You need to keep the /services/ before service1 otherwise it'll break

Comment: Ok, I'll add everything in the services folder to the pages folder and delete the services folder. What code do I add to .htaccess file and do I put it before or after the current code I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want **/services/** before your services, then you'll have to move your service pages to the "pages" folder where your other files are, and then replace

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /pages/$1.html
```